# Graded readers for Spanish?

Tags: electronic-resources, spanish, physical-resources, graded-readers

Graded readers are a good type of material for extensive reading. Where can I find graded readers in Spanish?

Answer (score 5):

Black Cat CIDEB hs graded readers for the following CEFR levels:

- [CEFR level A1](http://www.blackcat-cideb.com/en/catalogue/spanish/graded-readers-en/level-a1-en/); example title: El Zorro;
- [CEFR level A2](http://www.blackcat-cideb.com/en/catalogue/spanish/graded-readers-en/level-a2-en/); example titles: Lazarillo de Tormes, Cantar de Mio Cid;
- [CEFR level B1](http://www.blackcat-cideb.com/en/catalogue/spanish/graded-readers-en/level-b1-en/); example titles: Nieblo (by Miguel de Unamuno), Fuente Ovejuna (Lope de Vega), Carmen (Prosper Mérimée);
- [CEFR level B2](http://www.blackcat-cideb.com/en/catalogue/spanish/graded-readers-en/level-b2-en/); example titles: La casa de Bernarda Alba (F. G. Lorca), Don Quijote de la Mancha (Cervantes);
- [CEFR level C1](http://www.blackcat-cideb.com/en/catalogue/spanish/graded-readers-en/level-c1-en/); currently only one title: Don Juan Tenorio (Jose Zorrilla).

The books come with a CD and an app. They contain an introduction about the author, activities to develop skills, notes to facilitate text comprehension, illustrations to help you understand the text and some kind of "dossier" about topics in the story. There is no information about the required vocabulary; the CEFR level indications are all you get.

The publisher DIFUSIÓN also has several collections of graded readers or [lecturas graduadas](https://www.difusion.com/catalogo/lecturas), mostly for the levels A1 - B1. For example, the collection [Pepa Villa, taxista en Barcelona](https://www.difusion.com/catalogo/lecturas/pepa-villa-taxista-en-barcelona) is for adults at the levels A1-B1. The books contain explanatory notes on cultural and linguistic topics, and activities to practise the vocabulary used in the book. The collection [Novela histórica](https://www.difusion.com/catalogo/lecturas/novela-historica) is aimed at learners on level B1 and contains short historical novels. These books come with a CD with a narrated version of the story. The explanatory notes at the bottom of each page are in Spanish, but there is a glossary with English, French and German translations at the back of the book. 
There are also non-fiction titles, such as in the collection [Marca América Latina](https://www.difusion.com/catalogo/lecturas/marca-america-latina).

[ELI Graded Readers](http://www.eligradedreaders.com/en/) has graded readers for several languages. The graded readers for Spanish are available for the levels A1 to B2. There are separate series for three age groups: "Infantiles" (levels Sub-A1 to A2), "Adolescentes" (levels A1 to B1) and "Jóvenes y adultos" (levels A2 to B2).

The graded readers for "Jóvenes y adultos" include titles such as Bodas de Sangre (F. G. Lorca), Fuenteovejuna (Lope de Vega), La Celestina (Fernando de Rojas), Lazarillo de Tormes and Niebla (Miguel de Unamuno). These books come with an audio CD. The explanatory notes at the bottom of the page are in Spanish; there are questions to test text comprehension at the back of the book and a short biographical notice about the author.